# How can I add a custom endpoint for Stripe or any microservice webhook?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I have a **apollo graphql server**, I want to add a custom endpoint for that Stripe or some microservice, how can i add additional endpoints ?

I do not want to create a different project.

```
const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin:["https://localhost:3000"],
  credentials: true
};

// RESOLVERS
const resolvers = require("./graphql/resolvers/index");

const resolveFunctions = {
  JSON: GraphQLJSON,
  Upload: GraphQLUpload
};

// models
const Admin = require("./models/Admin");

const pubsub = new PubSub();

// SCHEMA
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: importSchema("./graphql/schema.graphql"),
  resolvers,
  resolveFunctions,
  context: ({ req }) => ({
    Admin,
    activeAdmin: req ? req.activeAdmin : null
  })
});

app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers["authorization"];
  if (token && token !== "null") {
    try {
      const activeAdmin = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
      req.activeAdmin = activeAdmin;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("ERROR", e);
    }
  }

  next();
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: corsOptions });
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
server.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer);

httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT || 4004, () =>
  console.log(
    ` Server ready at http://localhost:4004${server.graphqlPath}`
  )
);
```

so how can I add multiple enpoints for webhook?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's a tricky one. I don't think this is supported yet. However, there's a hack to use the playground endpoint for your webhook integration. There's an open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1908) that highlights a similar problem. I am quoting a workaround from that thread.

Quoting [mondaychen](https://github.com/mondaychen) from that thread.

> My plan is to add a new option playgroundPath in the argument of
> applyMiddleware. If not specified, it will be the same as path and
> everything will stay the same; when it is different from path, it will
> be used as the URL for the playground instead, but the endpoint will
> still be path. Meanwhile, a property playgroundPath is added to the
> server instance so people can read it from outside easily.

Here's an implementation of the same idea from [Pocket-titan](https://github.com/Pocket-titan)

```
import express from 'express'
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express'

const app = express()

const server = new ApolloServer({
    playground: {
        endpoint: `http://${your_domain_here}:${your_port_here}/graphql-playground`,
    },
})

server.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    path: '/api/graphql',
})

app.listen(your_port_here, () => {
    console.log(`Serving graphql api on /api/graphql and playground on /graphql-playground!`)
})
```